# How to describe a person working under you in the workplace?

Tags: terminology

I'm after a word that best describes a person that works under someone else.

For example, I had a joke with my manager saying that *I have to do his bidding because I'm his subordinate*. We laughed, then later thought what is the actual word for this relationship with a manager? Subordinate seems a little harsh for the context.

For context you could call this a standard office type work environment.

Note: I have also asked this on the English language exchange but thought I'd get a different angle here. I'm also in the UK.

Comment: Subordinate is the correct word. Why would you consider that harsh?

Comment: @HLGEM We have a relaxed work atmosphere in our team between us. Subordinate makes me think of military situations but if that's my wrong association then I'll accept using subordinate.

Comment: Direct Report works instead of subordinate.

Comment: Subordinate means that he is higher in the hierarchy than you are which he is because he is your manager. Working in a relaxed place doesn't change that. If there was a decisions to make that the two of you professionally disagreed on, his is the final word when he is the boss.

Comment: You could also use the word 'junior' but I don't like this word because it may be confused with other things (age, experience). Superior-subordinate relationship is typically independent of those things.

Comment: This is about word definition not the workplace.

Comment: "Lackey" is a good one, but I'm partial to "lickspittle".

Comment: Please can you explain your down vote? This is a totally legitimate question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subordinate is a correct word for it. If you don't like its flavor, you could use 'direct report' as well.

Answer (score 7):

### Direct Report

Direct Report - n. - an employee whose position at work is directly below that of another person, and who is managed by that person.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/direct-report

Comment: THIS   ^^^^  is it exactly

Answer (score 3):

Turning this phrase around makes things a little less forced in terms of colloquial English phrasing.

> I have to do his bidding because he's my boss.

This (to English ears) flows better than "subordinate" or "direct report" (even though they're technically correct).